# Save File Dialog , restrict name

Tags: c#, csv, savefiledialog

my program has a save file option which is shown below :

```
        //Browse for file
        SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "CSV|*.csv";
        ofd.DefaultExt = ".csv";

        DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        string converted = result.ToString();

        if (converted == "OK")
        {
            Master_Inventory_Export_savePath.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
```

if I write the file name as "example" it saves correctly as a .csv however if I set the name as "example.txt" it saves as a text file , I've looked on msdn etc but even setting the default extension doesn't prevent this , any ideas on how to only allow files of .csv to be saved ?

Comment: Few questions. 1st: why the h*** you convert DialogResult to string? 2nd: if user intentionally add an extension...why you have to change it to something else? Would you be happy if Notepad changes your extension to .txt when you're trying to save a HTML file you wrote?

Comment: @Adriano   I add the csv extension but i need to perform this check to remove the .txt or other extension so that the system works if the user types in the wrong extension

Comment: _"...if user intentionally adds..."_. I would feel upset if I write A.TXT and Excel will save A.CSV because I selected CSV **format**. That said better to prevent user to specify another extension if you don't want that (at least he won't be surprised to don't find what he asked for).

Comment: @Adriano I see your point, but on the flip side, i doubt he's writing any sort of multi-purpose program, such as a text editor, but probably something specific that expects certain types of inputs/outputs.

Comment: @user2366842 yes maybe. I thought I wouldn't because CSV is pretty common format and sometimes I wouldn't let it open directly by Excel (because it doesn't conform very well to CSV RFC).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [FileOk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok.aspx) event to check what your users type and refuse the input if they type something that you don't like.

For example:

```
SaveFileDialog sdlg = new SaveFileDialog();
sdlg.FileOk += CheckIfFileHasCorrectExtension;
sdlg.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
if(sdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    Console.WriteLine("Save file:" + sdlg.FileName);

 void CheckIfFileHasCorrectExtension(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
 {
     SaveFileDialog sv = (sender as SaveFileDialog);
     if(Path.GetExtension(sv.FileName).ToLower() != ".csv")
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
         MessageBox.Show("Please omit the extension or use 'CSV'");
         return;
     }
 }
```

The main advantage of this approach is that your SaveFileDialog is not dismissed and you could check the input without reloading the SaveFileDialog if something is wrong.

**BEWARE** the SaveFileDialog appends automatically your extension if it doesn't recognize the extension typed by your users. This means that if your users type `somefile.doc` then the SaveFileDialog doesn't append the .CSV extension because the .DOC extension is well known in the OS. But if your users type `somefile.zxc` then you receive as output (and also in the `FileOk` event) a FileName called `somefile.zxc.csv`

Comment: Thank you Steve. I used this method to disallow overwrite (new files only) in VB.net - SaveFileDialog is declared as *private WithEvents* and handler *Handles dialog.FileOk*, set *dialog.OverwritePrompt = False* to suppress the system overwrite message so the dialog jumps straight to a messagebox saying "Overwrite NOT allowed" - just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

can you not just force the .csv filetype by going like so in the last block of code?

```
if (converted == "OK")
{
    if (ofd.FileName.toString.EndsWith(".csv")<1)
    {
     Master_Inventory_Export_savePath.Text = ofd.FileName + ".csv";
    }
    else
    {
    Master_Inventory_Export_savePath.Text = ofd.FileName;
    }
}
```

Note - untested, but should give you a starting point....

Comment: yeah, this would run into problems with edge cases...Steve's answer is a bit more complete than this, this was just a quick thought.  Although I have updated it a little to work around the csv.other scenario.

Comment: Should at least change IndexOf to EndsWith.

Comment: @bland you're correct.  Didn't really think this one through entirely, i guess :)  Code updated to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

Set the property `AddExtension` to `true`.

```
ofd.AddExtension = true;
```

Comment: It'll add extension only if used doesn't supply one.

Comment: @AurelienC I tried that but still if i enter the filename as Exampl.txt it saves as a txt file